# $m-n$ is congruent and $m*n$ is congruent

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Suppose $m\equiv3(\mod 8)$ and $n\equiv6(\mod 8)$.

> Determine the number amount $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ to which
>   a) $m-n$ is congruent 
>   b) $mn$ is congruent

My solution:
$m\equiv 3(\mod 8)$

$8=3\times 2+2$ 

$3=2\times 1 \times 1 $

> I am stuck here.

Comment: " M≡3(mod 8) 8=3x2+2 3=2x1x1" .  That's not relevent at all.  When you have a mod b, you need to express a in terms of b.  Doing the opposite, expressing b in terms of a is mostly useless.

Answer (score 1):

$m\equiv 3 \mod 8$ means $m=8k +3$ for some $k$ and $n\equiv 6\mod 8$ means $n=8j+6$ for some $j $.

So $n-m= (8j+6)-(8k+3)=8 (j-k)+3$

So .....